# Comparison of two values with access to ancestors

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have to look in my XML for a value of the same reference and from this comparison, I have to find and get the data of the ancestors.
The XML looks like this:

```
<Section version="1" subversion="1" key="xy://data/Section/42df2def-b485-4600-9701-a9a0cb3fb0ba/?language=de-DE">
    <Heading>This is a heading</Heading>
    <Sequence version="1" subversion="1" key="xy://data/Sequence/70533309-defa-46af-a419-56e134ed0757/"> 
        <Target>How to do ABC</Target>
        <Step StepId="id12345">
            <Condition>
                <Para>First step.</Para>
                <Para>Do ... to get ...</Para>
            </Condition>
        </Step>
        <Step>
            <Condition>
                <Para>Second step.</Para>
                <Para>Reference: <StepRef StepIdRef="id12345"/></Para>
            </Condition>
        </Step>
    </Sequence>
</Section>

<Section version="1" subversion="1" key="xy://data/c2e4fa40-372e-4fe7-a63d-a73848c8f28b/?language=de-DE">
    <Heading>This is another heading</Heading>
    <Sequence version="1" subversion="1" key="27329b6b-95ef-4959-af95-f04f99391005/">
        <Target>How to do XYZ</Target>
        <Step>
            <Condition>
                <Para>Important step, see <StepRef StepIdRef="id12345"/></Para>
            </Condition>
        </Step>
    </Sequence>
</Section>
```

What I want should look like this:

```
<a href="" my.id="{key from Sequence}" my.version="{version from Sequence}" my.type="{name of object type}" fragment="{stepId_version_type}"/>
```

Transferred to my case both examples should look like this:

```
<p>Reference: <a href="" my.id="70533309-defa-46af-a419-56e134ed0757" my.version="1" my.type="Sequence" fragment="id12345_1_Sequence"/>
<p>Important step, see <a href="" my.id="70533309-defa-46af-a419-56e134ed0757" my.version="1" my.type="Sequence" fragment="id12345_1_Sequence"/>
```

And my XSLT looks like this so far:

```
<xsl:template match="StepRef">
    <xsl:param name="catchStep" select="StepIdRef">
        <xsl:if test="$catchStep=//@StepId">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href"/>

                <!-- To get the stepId -->
                <xsl:attribute name="my.id"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@key]/substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@key, 'data/'), '/'), '/')"/></xsl:attribtue>
                <!-- To get the version -->
                <xsl:attribute name="my.version"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@key]/@version"/></xsl:attribtue>
                <!-- To get the object type -->
                <xsl:attribute name="my.type"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*[@key]/substring-before(substring-after(@key, 'data/'), '/')"/></xsl:attribtue>

                <xsl:attribute name="fragment">
                    <!-- To get the stepId -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$firstStep"/>
                    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
                    <!-- To get the version -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[@key]/@version"/>
                    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
                    <!-- To get the object type -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[key]/substring-before(substring-after(@key, 'data/'), '/')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </a>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Main problems:**

- Somehow I always catch Section instead of Sequence (and I receive corresponding data)
- It seems like it only works for the steps in the same topic
- I don't know how I can access the same variable and make my XPath controls from there
- I don't think my XSLT is cleanly coded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could do with using an `xsl:key` here to look up the Steps

So, if you are in a template matching `StepRef` you can look up the referenced step by doing `key('Steps', @StepIdRef)` (and to get the parent, do `key('Steps', @StepIdRef)..`).

You can further streamline your code by using [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to make creating attributes much easier.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="Steps" match="Step" use="@StepId" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="StepRef">
    <xsl:variable name="object" select="key('Steps', @StepIdRef)/.." />
    <a href="" 
        my.id="{substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($object/@key, 'data/'), '/'), '/')}" 
        my.version="{$object/@version}" 
        my.type="{local-name($object)}"
        fragment="{@StepIdRef}_{$object/@version}_{local-name($object)}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, many thanks for your response. I just implemented it in my stylesheet and everything works perfectly. Thank you for the great solution and the tips in the representation of the attributes! Have a great day.